# When two opposing vortexes combine to form a dipole vortex, why does it always move in the same direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

AS you know, when two opposing vortexes combine to form a dipole vortex, it always move in the same direction as shown with red arrow in figure below. I wonder, why? is there a equation for this motion?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of this phenomenon happening? I have seen this when the eddies are produced by the two edges of an oar blade, but in that case the purpose of the oar blade was to cause bulk motion of the water.

Comment: yes many have. if one vortex of dipole is bigger than the other, smaller vortex turns around bigger vortex. if two vortex are equal, they move in the direction of inner flows between them. look at all these videos;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxlSCe111IA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpcqI11d3gc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP6ngTP8W80

https://youtu.be/rF3phfLv7QM?t=12

Comment: @HakanEgne it's simple to understand why just by considering the flow induced by one vortex at the position of the other vortex core. See this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/663790/226902